# (Logic Question) Where am I going wrong in these deduction?

Tags: logic

I am trying to solve this:

> 1. (Premise 1) $A \vee B$
> 2. (Premise 2) $\neg B \vee C$

Prove:  $A \vee C$

This is what I have done so far:
[First Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYPyh.png)

Edit:2
[Reached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJB1L.png)

Comment: Hint: Consider Or Form of Implication for Premise 2.

Comment: For that last step do not refer to the first two subproofs, but *do* refer to the disjunction $\neg B \lor C$. Since you're doing $\lor$ Elim on $\neg B \lor C$, you only want to refer to the subproofs that asume $\neg B$ and $C$ respectively, but of course you do have to refer to that very disjunction: *that*'s the $\lor$ you are 'eliminating'!

Comment: More pressingly though: I am sure you are not allowed to use Ana Con.  Ana Con is an Automated proving routine that is 'intelligent' and can check for logical consequence, but using that in a formal proof is a bit like 'cheating'.  In fact, notice that when you use Ana Con to go form lines 13 and 14 to 15, you are doing exactly what you need to prove for this argument as a whole!

Comment: @Ziryerx that would indeed work great ... if Fitch had that rule .. and it doesn't, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

In the second subproof, that assumes $B$, you realized that you need the $\neg B \lor C$ premise to get to $A \lor C$ (you use it on line 8). However, instead of using Ana Con, you should use proper rules of inference. So ... set up a $\lor$ Elim on $\neg B \lor C$ ... but do it *inside* the subproof that assumes $B$!

Comment: I missed my 2-3 lectures where all these things were covered so I am asking silly questions, so do we have create subproof for each premise?

Comment: @jkmnjik Oh, that's not good: better go to those lectures! Anyway, I am not sure what you mean by 'do we create a subproof for each premise' ... you certainly don't create a subproof where you assume a premise, because the premise is already *given*. However, when you have disjunction, that might be a good time to do some subproofs: one for each disjunction. Now, did you do what I said and do this for $\neg B \lor C$ ... but *inside* the subproof that assumes B?

Comment: Yeah I did, but I am not able to use  ^ elim on final answer

Comment: @jkmnjik On line 10 just get $A \lor C$

Comment: Also, the last $\lor$ elim is on line 1, not 3

Comment: I didn't saw the blunder I made on line 10 lol , I learned many things today all thanks to you

Comment: @jkmnjik Hey, glad I could help ... make sure to go to those lectures!

Comment: yeah I won't repeat that